# How i can bind two substring to one?

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx

I have two string

```
private StringProperties firstName;
private StringProperties lastName;
private StringProperties nickName;
```

the first and last name are picked by user, the nickName is a concatenation of first 3 character of first and lastname

How i can do that?

Actually i initialize it like that (this is the entire class).

```
public class Person {
private StringProperty firstName;
private StringProperty lastName;
private StringProperty nickName;
private ObservableList<Evento> eventi = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
    if (firstName.length() > 2 && lastName.length() > 2)
        this.nickName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName.trim().substring(0,3).concat(lastName.trim().substring(0,3)));
    else
        this.nickName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
}

public ObservableList<Evento> getEventi() {
    return eventi;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    if(firstName == null) firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"firstName");
    return firstName.get();
}

public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName.set(firstName);
}

public String getLastName() {
    if(lastName == null) lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
    return lastName.get();
}

public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName.set(lastName);
}

public String getNickName() {
    if(nickName == null) nickName = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"nickName");
    return nickName.get();
}

public StringProperty nickNameProperty() {
    return nickName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNickName() + "(" + getLastName() + " " + getFirstName() + ")";
}
```

}

but when i let the user change first or lastName, the nickName won't update.

Comment: Do you have other method for update `firstName` and `LastName`?

Comment: i have a GUI for update first and lastname, just edited the OP with the entire Person Class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `ReadOnlyStringProperty` for the nickname:

```
private ReadOnlyStringWrapper nickName= new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();
...
public final String getNickName() {
    return nickName.get();
}

public final ReadOnlyStringProperty nickNameProperty() {
    return nickName.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

As for binding, you can use utility methods from `Bindings` class or implement your own binding for any other complicated cases. This example uses `createStringBinding()` method. It takes `Callable` functional interface, which will be used to calculate new value, and list of observable properties, which values will be observed for changes:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);

    this.nickName.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(()->{
        if(this.firstName.get().length() > 2 && this.lastName.get().length() > 2) {
            return this.firstName.get().substring(0,3).concat(this.lastName.get().trim().substring(0,3));
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }, this.firstName, this.lastName));

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Bindings.format`:

```
nickName.bind(Bindings.format("%.3s%.3s", firstName, lastName));
```

The `3` in `%.3s` is the maximum length of the string.

---

This won't do any trimming of the strings though, (you could do that before passing the strings to `firstName` and `lastName`).

It will also work on strings that are smaller than 3 characters. So, you can get nicknames like `FoBar`, `FooB` or `Bar` (if the first name is an empty string).